# SQL Server 2008 adding Check Values

Tags: sql-server

I want to allow a column to accept only two values i.e. Open and Close statuses.How would I go through with it ?

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Short_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL,
DateModified DATETIME NULL,
CreatedBy INT NOT NULL,
ModifiedBy INT NULL,
Status VARCHAR(12) DEFAULT('Open') NOT NULL,
Description VARCHAR(255) NULL,
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    Short_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    DateModified DATETIME NULL, 
    CreatedBy INT NOT NULL, 
    ModifiedBy INT NULL, 
    Status VARCHAR(12) DEFAULT('Open') NOT NULL, 
    Description VARCHAR(255) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT chk_status_val CHECK(Status IN ('Open', 'Close'))
)
```